Spark Structured Streaming, when performing a Stream-to-Stream left join, it behaves like an inner join
I am employing the Medallion architecture, where I stream data from four Silver Delta tables. I then perform joins on these tables and sink the resulting data to the Gold layer using PySpark(Spark 3.4.0).
# orders silver
orders_silver_df = spark.readStream\
                        .format('delta')\
                        .option("ignoreChanges", "true")\
                        .load(path = ORDERS_SILVER_TABLE_PATH)\
                        .withWatermark("file_timestamp", "3 minutes")

# orderlines silver
orderlines_silver_df = spark.readStream\
                            .format('delta')\
                            .option("ignoreChanges", "true")\
                            .load(path = ORDERLINES_SILVER_TABLE_PATH)\
                            .transform(rename_orderline_cols_tf)\
                            .withWatermark("file_timestamp_OrderLine", "3 minutes")
                            

# # dropshipments silver
dropshipments_silver_df = spark.readStream \
                               .format('delta') \
                               .option("ignoreChanges", "true")\
                               .load(path = DROPSHIPMENTS_SILVER_TABLE_PATH)\
                               .transform(rename_dropshipment_cols_tf)\
                               .withWatermark("file_timestamp_Dropshipment", "3 minutes")
                               

# fulfillments silver
fulfillments_silver_df = spark.readStream \
                              .format('delta') \
                              .option("ignoreChanges", "true")\
                              .load(path = FULFILLMENTS_SILVER_TABLE_PATH)\
                              .transform(rename_fulfillment_cols_tf)\
                              .withWatermark("file_timestamp_Fulfillment", "3 minutes")

Here, you can observe that I'm setting up read streams for four Delta tables. In the transformation step, I'm simply altering the column names by appending a postfix. Additionally, I've configured watermarking for each stream with a duration of 3 minutes.
orders_gold_df = orders_silver_df.join(
                                          orderlines_silver_df,
               
                                          (orders_silver_df["OrderNo"] == orderlines_silver_df["OrderNo_OrderLine"]) & \
                                          (orders_silver_df["file_timestamp"] >= orderlines_silver_df["file_timestamp_OrderLine"] - F.expr('interval 3 minutes'))
                                          ,'leftOuter'
                                    )\
                                 .join(
                                          dropshipments_silver_df,

                                          (orderlines_silver_df["DropshipId_OrderLine"] == dropshipments_silver_df["DropshipId_Dropshipment"]) & \
                                          (orders_silver_df["file_timestamp"] >= dropshipments_silver_df["file_timestamp_Dropshipment"] - F.expr('interval 3 minutes'))
                                          ,'leftOuter'
                                    )\
                                 .join(
                                          fulfillments_silver_df,

                                          (orders_silver_df['OrderNo'] == fulfillments_silver_df["OrderNo_Fulfillment"]) & \
                                          (orders_silver_df["file_timestamp"] >= fulfillments_silver_df["file_timestamp_Fulfillment"] - F.expr('interval 3 minutes'))
                                          ,'leftOuter'
                                      ) 

orders_gold_df.transform(gold_table_tf)\
              .writeStream \
              .format('delta') \
              .option("ignoreChanges", "true") \
              .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
              .queryName("orders_gold_table")\
              .outputMode('append')\
              .trigger(processingTime='5 seconds') \
              .option('checkpointLocation', ORDERS_GOLD_CHECKPOINT)\
              .start(ORDERS_GOLD_TABLE_PATH)

Here you can see I am doing leftouter join and then on result dataframe i am just adding some new driverd column and selecting required columns and writting data to sink.
Now the issue is this left join is working like inner join. For example, if an order does not belong to a dropshipment, there won't be corresponding data in the dropshipment table, and this condition will not be met.
orderlines_silver_df["DropshipId_OrderLine"] == dropshipments_silver_df["DropshipId_Dropshipment"]

In this scenario, when an order doesn't belong to a dropshipment, the dropshipment column in the sink table should have null values. However, the data isn't being written to the output gold table, which is unexpected. This behavior resembles an inner join, but I'm using a left join, so rows with this scenario should be written to the sink table. Currently, data is only sinking into the output gold table when all conditions are met.
I have thoroughly reviewed the documentation and conducted extensive research. Additionally, I've found several questions related to my problem, and their answers have been marked as correct. However, I am still uncertain about how those solutions are functioning, as they do not seem to work in my case. Could you please advise if I might be overlooking something?
I have also conducted tests to verify whether the watermark is functioning correctly. I observed that the states are indeed clearing after 3 minutes, and in the Spark UI, I can see that the job is triggering for my scenario. Furthermore, in the DAG visualization, it is evident that the data is not found in the dropshipment table. Despite these confirmations, I am still uncertain why it is not operating as a left join.
